# Can Kollros' Theorem w/ extra turns be seen via inversive geometry?

Tags: geometry

[Kollros' Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KollrosTheorem.html), with extended turns allowed, says

> For every ring containing $p$ spheres, there exists a ring of $q$ spheres, each touching each of the $p$ spheres [...] if more than one turn is allowed, then $$(p-2r)(q-2s)=4rs\quad\quad\left[\text{ or }\frac{r}{p}+\frac{s}{q}=\frac{1}{2},\text{ -anon }\right]$$ where $r$ and $s$ are the numbers of turns on both necklaces before closing.

(The first sentence looks like it contains an error: there shouldn't be a $q$ for every $p$ - most likely it should read that two interlocking rings of spheres correspond to solutions to the Diophantine equation and vice-versa.)

Firstly, in terms of tangencies and intersections, what precisely *is* a turn? Secondly, can this be seen via [inversive geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry) in an analogous way to [Soddy's hexlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soddy's_hexlet) ($r=s=1$, $p=3$, $q=6$)? Inversion preserves tangencies, and sends spheres intersecting the center of inversion to planes, so for Soddy's hexlet we can invert about any tangent point of the first ring of $3$ spheres so that we get two parallel planes and a sphere stuck between them, reducing the problem of finding the interlocking ring of spheres to the annular case, which is equivalent to working with a [Steiner chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_chain) (or more specifically the [kissing number problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number_problem)), and the $p=4$, $q=4$ case can be reduced similarly.

$\hskip 0.2in$ [image: Soddy's hexlet] [image: annular hexlet]

There doesn't appear to be any reference for this, as MathWorld cites a "personal communication."